# Android Studio defining lint rules

Tags: android, lint

I made inspection on a whole project and got the following issue on file X with issue id `SpellCheckingInspection`. My question is what is the ID of declared issue in lint.xml that ignores on spelling just file X from project ?

**lint.xml**

```
<lint>  
    <issue id="????">
        <ignore path="X" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Answer (score 0):

@vasile AFAIK The issue id should be "Typos" and X should be path of the file that you want to ignore.

Here is the list of [android lint check ID's](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)